# Java Annotation Processing Messager API only shows Errors

Tags: java, eclipse, annotation-processing

I use the Java Annotation Processing API to process some of my classes. This also includes to validates various aspects of the processed classes. When an error occurs, I use the Messager API to print the error.

```
processingEnvironment.getMessager().printMessage(Kind.ERROR, "error", element);
```

This works fine and all errors are displayed as errors in the editor (eclipse). They show up in the editor, the problems view and the error log which is exactly what I expect.

As long as the processed file contains at least one error, all errors and warnings show up in all theses three views. The problem is that when a file only has warnings they only show up in the error log.

I print the warnings like this:

```
processingEnvironment.getMessager().printMessage(Kind.WARNING, "msg", element);
```

but I've also tried to print them as `MANDATORY_WARNING.

Is there a way to tell eclipse to show the warnings in the editor and problems view, too, as it is the case when the file has errors?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I'm also seeing some very strange behaviour with errors not showing up in the Eclipse editor or error log. In my case they either all show up or don't show up at all. The problem seems to be (somehow) related to generated source file(s), as by changing one of their names from a class with existing references in the (non-generated) code to a brand new class name I can make all errors disappear and appear respectively, regardless of what elements the errors are on. Very strange!

Comment: Hi, no I didn't solve this problem. I now just write a log file with all the errors.

Comment: Please, what tutorial did you use? For I cannot make Eclipse to show an error called i the Processor.